# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Goal() expected, got #<Goal id: ... > which is an instance of Goal()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three classes, Goal, Asset and DesiredAsset. The latter has relations `belongs_to :goal` and `belongs_to :asset`, and I got this error when trying to create a DesiredAsset record. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
goal = Goal.find_by!(...) # => #<Goal:0x00007facb992e358 id: 14258, name: ... >
asset = Asset.find_by!(...) # => #<Asset:0x00007facb8696c68 id: 9659, ... >

DesiredAsset.create_with(weight: 0.0).find_or_create_by!(goal: goal, asset: asset)
# => ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Goal(#70189908142360) expected, got #<Goal id: 14258, name: ... > which is an instance of Goal(#70190077602420)
```

I've found similar questions, but all of them are a real mismatch (eg. `Team() expected, got String()`). But in my case it doesn't look like a mismatch because it's the same `Goal` class.

Using Rails 6.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strange... Have you tested this? `DesiredAsset.create_with(weight: 0.0).find_or_create_by!(goal_id: goal.id, asset_id: asset.id)`

Comment: That worked! Any ideas why it works this way but not passing the instance directly?

Comment: Is there any chance that you are changing the Goal class in some way, for example with a dynamic method definition, or are you doing an explicit `require` in one of your files. Also, in your associations, maybe you have used `class_name: Goal` rather than `class_name: 'Goal'`

Comment: Passing ids is a sign of an issue with associations. Can you post the associations you have in each of the three classes? Do you have a #has_many association for DesiredAsset in each of Goal and Asset?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and killing the server, then running `spring stop` fixed it.

I suggest you use block syntax for `find_or_create_by` instead of `create_with` as specified in [ruby docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).

```
DesiredAsset.find_or_create_by!(goal: goal, asset: asset) do |desired_asset|
  desired_asset.weight = 0.0
end
```